# Khintchine inequality (question about Holder inequality)

Tags: probability, inequality, lp-spaces

I'm reading a proof of a Khintchine inequality :

> Let $(r_{1}, \dots , r_{n})$ be iid random variables with $P(r_{i} = \pm1) = \frac{1}{2}$. Let $f = \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}a_{j}r_{j}$,
>   where $a_{j} \in \mathbb{R}$.
>
> Then $||f||_{2} \leq \sqrt{e}||f||_{1}$.

The proof uses Holder : $\forall g \in L^{\infty}, ||fg||_{1}\leq||f||_{1}||g||_{\infty}$, and then takes $$g = \prod\limits_{j=1}^{n}(1 + ia_{j}r_{j})$$

But I don't understand why we can take such a function, and still use Holder.  I believe that $f,g$ must lie in $L^{p}$ spaces defined over the same space $S$ for that.

Comment: You have $f,g\in L^\infty(S)$, where $S$ is your probability space. What's the problem?

Comment: The thing is, in the proof, the norms are associated with the space $\text{span}_{\mathbb{R}}(r_{1}, \dots, r_{n})$, and it seems to me that $g$ is not an element of this space.

Comment: Maybe you should add more of these details to your question, then.